# core-plot iOS reversed Y axis

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-plot

I would like to use core-plot to display a water depth graph (updated in real time) but I can't figure out how to reverse the Y axis, so that the X axis (representing the time domain) is on the top of my UIView and the Y axis grows towards the bottom with positive values.

**EDIT**

It would be even better if I could draw axes like this:
- X axis is time
- Y axis is from 0 to X (X > 0) and on the top there is 0, on the bottom there is X
- X axis is on the bottom

ASCII version:

**0 |

1 |

.

.

.

x |

--------------------------**
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a negative length for the plot range to reverse the direction of an axis. For example (from the axis demo in CPTTestApp):

```
plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromDouble(0.0)
                                                length:CPTDecimalFromDouble(-10.0)];
```

Comment: If you read my question, I'd like to reverse the Y axis. I have tried your solution before submitting the question and it fails to work :(

Comment: I could post you my code, but it's almost the same as the scatter plot speed test example in the Core Plot distribution.

Comment: For the y-axis, just replace `xRange` with `yRange` in the code I posted above. The location of a plot range is always the value at the left side of the graph (for the x-axis) and the bottom of the graph (for the y-axis). The magnitude of the length determines how many units are in the range and the sign determines whether it counts up or down.

Comment: If I did what you mention here, the Y axis disappeared. And the X axis stayed at the bottom of my view. Maybe it is a bug in core-plot, I don't know.

Comment: Did you try location = x and length = -x for the yRange?

Comment: Yes of course, this was the first thing I tried. Even before registering to stack overflow :)

Comment: I think I misunderstood your last comment. It's working now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being a bit tricky to understand from the accepted answer.  To add another example for anyone having issues understanding how to flip the y axis values in coreplot, you really need to declare the **plotRangeWithLocation** to be the positive number you want to achieve, then set the length to the **same negative number** like this:

```
plotSpacePressureLeft.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(9000)
 length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(-9000)];
```

This produces a y-axis like this as of iOS 14 and coreplot mid 2020 versions:

[image: This produces a y-axis like this]