# CorePlot - spacing of Bars in bar chart

Tags: ios, core-plot

I'm trying to layout my barchart nicely. I'd like to have no more than 10 horizontal bars all anchored to the top with a set bar width and bar spacing.

```
#define kBarHeight 20
#define kBarSpacing 8
myPlotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromInt([self.data count]*(kBarHeight+kBarSpacing)) length:CPTDecimalFromInt([self.data count]*(kBarHeight+kBarSpacing) * -1)];
```

The negatives is because I'm trying also to get [this effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6037318/core-plot-ios-reversed-y-axis)

```
-(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
NSNumber *num = @0;

switch (fieldEnum) {
    case CPTBarPlotFieldBarTip:
        if ([plot.identifier isEqual:@"dataset1"]) {
            num = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[self.dataSet1[index] count]];
        } else {
            num = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[self.dataSet2[index] count]];

        }
        break;

    default:
        num = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:(index*(kBarHeight + kBarSpacing)) + kBarHeight/2 ]; 
        break;
}
return num;

}
```

I thought the above would work, <del>but all the bars are on top of eachother near the bottom of the chart, and cut off half way</del> but they're still evenly spaced and not listening to the bar spacing value I'm setting. . Thoughts?

Edit: Full graph set up:

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark - Chart behavior
-(void)initPlot {
    [self configureGraph];
    [self configurePlots];
    [self configureAxes];
}

-(void)configureGraph {

    CPTGraph *dataSet2Graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:self.dataSet2Graph.bounds];
    CPTGraph *dataSet1Graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:self.dataSet1Graph.bounds];

    dataSet2Graph.plotAreaFrame.masksToBorder = NO;
    dataSet1Graph.plotAreaFrame.masksToBorder = NO;

    dataSet2Graph.paddingLeft = 150.0;
    dataSet1Graph.paddingLeft = 150.0;

    self.dataSet2Graph.hostedGraph = dataSet2Graph;
    self.dataSet1Graph.hostedGraph = dataSet1Graph;


    CPTXYPlotSpace *dataSet2PlotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *) dataSet2Graph.defaultPlotSpace;
    CSGeoStat *stat = (CSGeoStat *) self.dataSet2Data[0]; //Biggest dataSet2 count

    dataSet2PlotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.0) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(stat.count * 1.1)];
    dataSet2PlotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromInt([self.dataSet2Data count]) length:CPTDecimalFromInt(-1 * [self.dataSet2Data count])];

    CPTXYPlotSpace *dataSet1PlotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *) dataSet1Graph.defaultPlotSpace;
    stat = (CSGeoStat *) self.dataSet1Data[0]; //Biggest tz count

    dataSet1PlotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.0) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(stat.count * 1.1)];
    dataSet1PlotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromInt([self.dataSet1Data count]*(kBarHeight+kBarSpacing)) length:CPTDecimalFromInt([self.dataSet1Data count]*(kBarHeight+kBarSpacing) * -1)];




    [self.dataSet2Graph setFrame:CGRectMake(self.dataSet2Graph.frame.origin.x,
                                            self.dataSet2Graph.frame.origin.y,
                                            self.dataSet2Graph.frame.size.width,
                                            (int)([self.dataSet2Data count]*(kBarHeight+kBarSpacing)*1.2))];
    [self.dataSet1Graph setFrame:CGRectMake(self.dataSet1Graph.frame.origin.x,
                                           self.dataSet1Graph.frame.origin.y,
                                           self.dataSet1Graph.frame.size.width,
                                           (int)([self.dataSet1Data count]*(kBarHeight+kBarSpacing)*1.2))];


}

-(void)configurePlots {




    CPTBarPlot *dataSet2Plot  = [[CPTBarPlot alloc] init];
    dataSet2Plot.barsAreHorizontal             = YES;
    dataSet2Plot.barCornerRadius               = CPTFloat(1.0);
    dataSet2Plot.identifier = @"CountryPlot";
    dataSet2Plot.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor colorWithComponentRed:19/255 green:221/255 blue:187/255 alpha:1]];



    CPTBarPlot *dataSet1Plot  = [[CPTBarPlot alloc] init];
    dataSet1Plot.barsAreHorizontal             = YES;
    dataSet1Plot.barCornerRadius               = CPTFloat(1.0);
    dataSet1Plot.identifier = @"TimeZonePlot";
    dataSet1Plot.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor colorWithComponentRed:19/255 green:221/255 blue:188/255 alpha:1]];


    CPTMutableLineStyle *barLineStyle = [[CPTMutableLineStyle alloc] init];
    barLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor clearColor];
    barLineStyle.lineWidth = 0.5;

    CPTGraph *dataSet2Graph = self.dataSet2Graph.hostedGraph;
    CPTGraph *dataSet1Graph = self.dataSet1Graph.hostedGraph;

    dataSet2Plot.dataSource = self;
    dataSet2Plot.delegate = self;
    dataSet2Plot.barWidth = CPTDecimalFromDouble(kBarHeight);
    dataSet2Plot.barWidthsAreInViewCoordinates = YES;
    dataSet2Plot.baseValue = CPTDecimalFromString(@"0");
    dataSet2Plot.lineStyle = barLineStyle;
    dataSet2Plot.barOffset = CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.25f);
    dataSet2Plot.labelOffset = -5.0;
    [dataSet2Graph addPlot:dataSet2Plot toPlotSpace:dataSet2Graph.defaultPlotSpace];


    dataSet1Plot.dataSource = self;
    dataSet1Plot.delegate = self;
    dataSet1Plot.baseValue = CPTDecimalFromString(@"0");
    dataSet1Plot.barWidth = CPTDecimalFromDouble(kBarHeight);
    dataSet1Plot.barWidthsAreInViewCoordinates = YES;

    dataSet1Plot.lineStyle = barLineStyle;
    dataSet1Plot.labelOffset = -5.0;
    dataSet1Plot.barOffset = CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.25f);

    [dataSet1Graph addPlot:dataSet1Plot toPlotSpace:dataSet1Graph.defaultPlotSpace];

}



-(void)configureAxes {



    CPTXYAxisSet *dataSet2AxisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *) self.dataSet2Graph.hostedGraph.axisSet;

    CPTXYAxis *x = dataSet2AxisSet.xAxis;

    x.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
    x.axisLineStyle = nil;

    CPTXYAxis *y = dataSet2AxisSet.yAxis;

    y.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
    y.axisLineStyle = nil;


    NSMutableArray *customLabels = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    [self.dataSet2Data enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(CSGeoStat *stat, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        NSString *labelText = stat.term;
        CPTMutableTextStyle *textStyle = [y.labelTextStyle mutableCopy];
        textStyle.color = [CPTColor whiteColor];

        CPTAxisLabel *label = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc] initWithText:labelText textStyle:textStyle];
        label.tickLocation = CPTDecimalFromInt((idx*(kBarHeight + kBarSpacing)) + kBarHeight/2);
        label.offset = y.labelOffset + y.majorTickLength;
        label.rotation    = M_PI * 2;
        [customLabels addObject:label];
    }];
    y.axisLabels = [NSSet setWithArray:customLabels];


    CPTXYAxisSet *dataSet1AxisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *) self.dataSet1Graph.hostedGraph.axisSet;

    CPTXYAxis *x2 = dataSet1AxisSet.xAxis;

    x2.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
    x2.axisLineStyle = nil;

    CPTXYAxis *y2 = dataSet1AxisSet.yAxis;

    y2.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
    y2.axisLineStyle = nil;

    NSMutableArray *customLabels2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    [self.dataSet1Data enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(CSGeoStat *stat, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        NSString *labelText = stat.term;
        CPTMutableTextStyle *textStyle = [y2.labelTextStyle mutableCopy];
        textStyle.color = [CPTColor whiteColor];

        CPTAxisLabel *label = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc] initWithText:labelText textStyle:textStyle];
        label.tickLocation = CPTDecimalFromInt((idx*(kBarHeight + kBarSpacing)) + kBarHeight/2);
        label.offset = y2.labelOffset + y2.majorTickLength;
        label.rotation    = M_PI * 2;
        [customLabels2 addObject:label];
    }];
    y2.axisLabels = [NSSet setWithArray:customLabels2];




}
```

Comment: Are the numbers returned from the datasource what you expect? If so, the problem is in the axis or plot setup.

Comment: Yes, I think so. I've now attached my full graph set up

Comment: Are the two hosting views positioned correctly in their parent view? Is the size correct? (The hosting view will make its hosted graph fit the hosting view.) It's hard to tell what's going on since the hosting views and graphs have the same names. The `yRange` of the two plot spaces are different. Is that intentional?

Comment: The hosting view frame was a little off. I've changed this now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the hosting view's size was an issue, I thought forcing just the plot range would do it, but I had to do additional frame resizing to get the desired effect

```
-(void)configureGraph {

    CPTGraph *dataSet1Graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:self.dataSet1Graph.bounds];
    CPTGraph *dataSet2Graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:self.dataSet2Graph.bounds];

    dataSet1Graph.plotAreaFrame.masksToBorder = NO;
    dataSet2Graph.plotAreaFrame.masksToBorder = NO;

    dataSet1Graph.paddingLeft = 150.0;
    dataSet2Graph.paddingLeft = 150.0;

    self.dataSet1Graph.hostedGraph = dataSet1Graph;
    self.dataSet2Graph.hostedGraph = dataSet2Graph;


    CPTXYPlotSpace *dataSet1PlotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *) dataSet1Graph.defaultPlotSpace;
    CSGeoStat *stat = (CSGeoStat *) self.dataSet1Data[0]; //Biggest dataSet1 count

    dataSet1PlotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.0) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(stat.count * 1.1)];
    dataSet1PlotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromInt([self.dataSet1Data count]*(kBarHeight+kBarSpacing) ) length:CPTDecimalFromInt(-1 * [self.dataSet1Data count]*(kBarHeight+kBarSpacing))];

    CPTXYPlotSpace *dataSet2PlotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *) dataSet2Graph.defaultPlotSpace;
    stat = (CSGeoStat *) self.dataSet2Data[0]; //Biggest tz count

    dataSet2PlotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.0) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(stat.count * 1.1)];
    dataSet2PlotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromInt([self.dataSet2Data count]*(kBarHeight+kBarSpacing)) length:CPTDecimalFromInt([self.dataSet2Data count]*(kBarHeight+kBarSpacing) * -1)];




    [self.dataSet1Graph setFrame:CGRectMake(self.dataSet1Graph.frame.origin.x,
                                            self.dataSet1Graph.frame.origin.y,
                                            self.dataSet1Graph.frame.size.width,
                                            (int)([self.dataSet1Data count]*(kBarHeight+kBarSpacing) + kBarHeight ))];
    [self.dataSet2Graph setFrame:CGRectMake(self.dataSet2Graph.frame.origin.x,
                                           self.dataSet2Graph.frame.origin.y,
                                           self.dataSet2Graph.frame.size.width,
                                           (int)([self.dataSet2Data count]*(kBarHeight+kBarSpacing) + kBarHeight))];


}
```